# Building a case sensitive dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am tasked with creating a dictionary that translates the words from the list `lst` into Swedish, based on the simple dictionary. If the word is not in the dictionary, just return it as it is. We have to use a function.

Here is the problem: I want to make sure the word "Merry" gets read in lower case, otherwise Python will not realize I am referring to the key "merry" in the dictionary, due to its case sensitivity (thus `i.lower()`). BUT, I would like the returned value to be "God" and not "god", and I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
dictionary = {"merry": "god", "christmas": "jul", "and": "och",
              "happy": "gott", "new": "nytt", "year": "ar"}


def translate(lst):
    new_list = []   #create an empty list to start with
    for i in lst: #to shuffle through every word in the list "lst"
        i = i.lower()   #to make sure we don't mess up the translation because of a upper case letter
        if i in dictionary.keys():  #look up in the keys
            new_list.append(dictionary[i])  #we want the value of the key i.
        else:
            new_list.append(i)  #return i if it does not exist in the dictionary.
            

    return new_list

# test
print(translate(['Merry', 'christmas', 'and', 'happy', 'new', 'year', 'mom']))
```

Comment: That would be non-trivial, you'd have to analyse the casing of the original (lower, upper, title, etc...) before lowercasing for lookup and apply the same casing on the output. And then you'll likely have a second issue that Python easily doesn't do localised casing / casefolding (I think it just passes the buck to the libc via the non-thread-safe locale garbage) but you might want that in order to respect language rules (I don't know if swedish has special casing rules).

Comment: Also `str.casefold` (and ensuring you have casefolded keys) might be better than lowercasing.

Comment: Have you tried this:
` for i in lst:
      if i.lower() in dictionary.keys():`

Comment: Another problem maybe later is that some languages change word orders and do not have same uppercasing rules. But maybee this is not the case for English <> Swedish translation ? so do you need upercasing only the first letter of the first word ? or any uppercase letter in the whole text ?

Comment: What do you want *exactly*? Do you want the first word in the translated sentence (list) to be capitalized, or do you want translated words to be capitalized if their original was capitalized? Or do you really only want the specific word "god" to be capitalized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this. One is to add the capitalized versions of the words to the dictionary.

```
dictionary = {"merry": "god", "christmas": "jul", "and": "och",
              "happy": "gott", "new": "nytt", "year": "ar"}
capitalized_dictionary = { key.capitalize():value.capitalize() for key, value in dictionary.items() }
dictionary.update(capitalized_dictionary)



def translate(lst):
    new_list = []   #create an empty list to start with
    for i in lst: #to shuffle through every word in the list "lst"
        # Don't need to convert to lower any more
        if i in dictionary.keys():  #look up in the keys
            new_list.append(dictionary[i])  #we want the value of the key i.
        else:
            new_list.append(i)  #return i if it does not exist in the dictionary.
            

    return new_list

# test
print(translate(['Merry', 'christmas', 'and', 'happy', 'new', 'year', 'mom']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [isupper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) to check if the first character of the input word is capital and [capitalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) to capitalize the matching word.

```py
dictionary = {"merry": "god", "christmas": "jul", "and": "och",
              "happy": "gott", "new": "nytt", "year": "ar"}


def translate(lst):
    new_list = []
    for i in lst:
        if i.lower() in dictionary.keys():
            match = dictionary[i.lower()]
            if i[0].isupper(): # Check if the first letter of `i` is a capital letter.
                match = match.capitalize() # Capitalize the matching translation
            new_list.append(match)
        else:
            new_list.append(i)

    return new_list

# test
print(translate(['Merry', 'christmas', 'and', 'happy', 'new', 'year', 'mom']))

>>> ['God', 'jul', 'och', 'gott', 'nytt', 'ar', 'mom']
```